# How to select elements from a list as a range of names to build a new list?

Tags: r, list, select, subset, names

I have a list of `spec_list`. I would like to get a new list by keeping elements from `AE:SUPPCM`. How can I do that?

I can do `lst2 <- spec_list[c('AE', 'SUPPAE', 'CM',' SUPPCM')]`, but can I do this using `AE:SUPPCM` instead of listing the names one by one?

```
str(spec_list, 1)
# List of 9
#  $ README          : chr "foobar"
#  $ SIGN_OFF        : logi TRUE
#  $ REVISION_HISTORY: logi NA
#  $ Study           : num 12345
#  $ Datasets        :List of 2
#  $ AE              : chr "yes"
#  $ SUPPAE          : int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#  $ CM              : num 1.23e+08
#  $ SUPPCM          : int [1:3, 1:4] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

Comment: Try this: `lst2 <- spec_list[c('AE:SUPPCM')]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a small function that can help you do that -

```
select_by_names <- function(data, x, y) {
  nm <- names(data)
  data[match(x, nm) : match(y, nm)]
}
```

I have created my own example to show how this function works.

```
tmp <- head(mtcars, 2)
spec_list <- list(README = tmp, `SIGN-OFF` = tmp, `REVISION HISTORY` = tmp, 
                  AE = tmp, SUPPAE = tmp, CM = tmp, SUPPCM = tmp)

select_by_names(spec_list, 'AE', 'SUPPCM')

#$AE
#              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4

#$SUPPAE
#              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4

#$CM
#              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4

#$SUPPCM
#              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
```

and another one -

```
select_by_names(spec_list, 'SIGN-OFF', 'CM')

#$`SIGN-OFF`
#              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4

#$`REVISION HISTORY`
#              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4

#$AE
#              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4

#$SUPPAE
#              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4

#$CM
#              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
```

Answer (score 2):

This is easy if your list was a data.frame.

```
subset(head(mtcars), select=qsec:carb)
#                    qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4         16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag     17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710        18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet 4 Drive    19.44  1  0    3    1
# Hornet Sportabout 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Valiant           20.22  1  0    3    1
```

It dispatches to `subset.data.frame`, which we can slightly change to make it work for lists.

```
select <- \(x, select, ...) {
  if (missing(select)) {
    vars <- rep_len(TRUE, length(x))
  } else {
    nl <- as.list(seq_along(x))
    names(nl) <- names(x)
    vars <-  eval(substitute(select), nl, parent.frame())
  }
  x[vars]
}
```

### Usage

```
select(x=spec_list, select=AE:SUPPCM)

## or shortly
select(spec_list, AE:SUPPCM)
# $AE
# [1] "yes"
# 
# $SUPPAE
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
# 
# $CM
# [1] 123248756
# 
# $SUPPCM
# [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    4    7   10
# [2,]    2    5    8   11
# [3,]    3    6    9   12
```

Also works with numbers,

```
select(spec_list, 6:9)
```

and of course with `"data.frame"`s.

```
select(mtcars, qsec:carb)
```

---

*Data:*

```
spec_list <- list(README='foobar', SIGN_OFF=TRUE, REVISION_HISTORY=NA, 
                  Study=12345, Datasets=list(iris, mtcars), AE='yes', 
                  SUPPAE=1:10, CM=123248756, SUPPCM=matrix(1:12, 3, 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

':' Dos work if you are ok with using the index and not the df-names

```
lst2 <- spec_list[6:9]
```

Comment: Is it a way to get index directly instead of counting 